# What is the best payment gateway for very small payments of between 50 pence and £1?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

This is a niche market but the way payment gateways set their pricing makes it A LOT more expensive for very small payments. The website I am working on will only take payments of less than a pound, so it is important to find the best payment gateway for this.

The cheapest I have been able to find so far is by Go Cardless: https://gocardless.com/pricing/ who charge 1% flat fee on transactions - but with a minimum of 20p per transaction. So I will be paying 20p for every transaction, this is 25% if the customer is paying 80p.

Anyone know of any cheaper options?

(Note: increasing customer payments isn't an option for this project)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered batch payments? For instance, keeping the individual requests without charging them (just authorizing), and if a shopper pays for multiple purchases over a month charging them once for the entire month purchases? This could save you on charges.

Comment: @Assafs that's a good idea and I hadn't considered that, however unfortunately these will be one off payments.